# React Native Router Flux Actions.currentParams props

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

This is not a problem, more of a curious question.

I have been using `Actions.currentParams` props for awhile now to either get Object information on current screen or to do things like `Actions.currentParams.backAndroidHandler()` to access the function I passed to RNRF's `Router`.

I found this trick upon browsing on threads, but found no explanations for it and how it works.
Couldn't find any documentation either on RNRF's github. Any information I have now are mainly based on printing the props to console and dissecting and speculating answers from that. I guess it just bugs me to operate blindly like this without concrete documentation on the things I use in my code.

If you have any information on this, links to material readings would be greatly appreciated, because it's been bugging me for DAYS now! lol

Answer (score 0):

I found something in [document](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/7939cd72f2df2b4f6eae7f931a7c654d0a52b9bc/src/Store.js#L558).

It looks have some relevance. Hope it helps.

```js
...
onNavigationStateChange = async (prevState, currentState, action) => {
    this.state = currentState;
    this.prevState = prevState;
    const activeState = getActiveState(this.state);
    const currentScene = activeState.routeName;
    this.currentParams = { ...activeState.params, ...action.params }; //Here!!
    this.currentScene = currentScene;
    this.prevScene = this.prevState ? getActiveState(this.prevState).routeName : null;
    if (this.currentScene !== this.prevScene) {
      // run onExit for old scene
      this.onExitHandler(this.prevScene);
      setTimeout(() => this.dispatch({
        type: ActionConst.FOCUS,
        routeName: this.currentScene,
        params: this.currentParams,
      }));
      this.onEnterHandler(currentScene);
}
...
```